# The two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following common distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

EDIT: here is the formatting of the problem. I already solved a) and b), I attempted to solve c) and struggle with d)

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
X \setminus Y & 0 & 1  \\
\hline
-1 & 0 & 1/3 \\
0 & 1/3 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1/3 
\end{array}
$$

a) Are X and Y independent ?

b) Find expectation value of X and Y

c) Find Variance of X and Y

d) Find Cov(X,Y) and $\rho =$ Corr(X,Y)

---

a) No, because for example P(X=1) = 1/3, P(Y=1) = 1/3 + 1/3 = 2/3, but $P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=1) = 2/9 \neq P(X=1, Y=1) = 1/3$. Is this correct ?

b) The expectation value is $E[X] = x_1p_1 + ... x_np_n$. So we have $E[X] = -1 \cdot 1/3 + 0 \cdot 1/3 + 1 \cdot 1/3 = 0$, $E[Y] = 0 \cdot 1/3 + 1 \cdot 2/3 = 2/3$.

They give the solutions $E[X] = 0, E[Y] = 2/3$, but not how they got them. Is the method I used correct or is this a coincidence ?

c) Now here, I don't understand because as far as I know the formula for variance is ∑$(x_i - µ)^2 / N$ where µ is the average value, $N$ the size of the sample, and $x_i$ are the values of $X$.

They give as solutions Var($X$) $= 2/3$, Var($Y$) $= 2/9$

For $X$, I get µ $= (-1 + 0 + 1) / 3 = 0$, so Var($X$) $= ( (-1 - 0)^2 + (0 - 0)^2 + (1 - 0)^2 ) / 3 = 1/3 + 1/3 = 2/3$

But for $Y$, I get µ $= (0 + 1) / 2 = 1/2$, so Var($Y$) $= ( (0 - 1/2)^2 + (1 - 1/2)^2 ) / 2 = (1/4 + 1/4) / 2 = 1/4 \neq 2/9$

What did I do wrong ? Or is my formula for variance wrong ?

d) Here, they give as solution Cov(X,Y) = Corr(X,Y) $= 0$, do you know how they got this result ?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144780/discussion-on-question-by-wengen-the-two-random-variables-x-and-y-have-the-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, hopefully I can answer my own question

a) and b) seem to be correct, as confirmed by @KurtG. and @drhab

For c), $$[^2]=(−1)^2⋅1/3+0^2⋅1/3+1^2⋅1/3=2/3$$  so that means $$[^2]−[]^2=2/3−0^2=2/3.$$ And for , we get $$[^2]=0^2⋅1/3+1^2⋅2/3=2/3$$ so that means $$[^2]−[]^2=2/3−(2/3)^2=6/9−4/9=2/9$$

For d), we can use

$$E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$ with $$E[XY] = ()⋅()=(−1⋅0)⋅0+(−1⋅1)⋅1/3+(0⋅0)⋅1/3+(0⋅1)⋅0+(1⋅0)⋅0+(1⋅1)⋅1/3=−1/3+1/3=0$$
so we have $$E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0 - 0 \cdot 2/3 = 0$$

Hopefully someone will read this in the future and find it useful !